# Getting comparison of Fixnum with nil failed when trying to set restrictions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, comparison, fixnum

In my app I have a table of venues where each can be on either a free or premium plan and each can have multiple venuephotos.

I'm trying to set it so that free venues can have a maximum of 3 venuephotos whilst premium venues can have up to 10 venuephotos.

**Venue.rb**

The plans are set as:

```
PLANS = %w[free premium]
```

The venuephoto limit is also set as:

```
def photo_limit
    {:free => 3, :premium => 10}[plan]
end
```

**Venuephoto.rb**

I then have this to check if the limit has been reached yet:

```
validate :venuephoto_count_within_limit, :on => :create

def venuephoto_count_within_limit
  if self.venue.venuephotos(:reload).count >= self.venue.photo_limit
    errors.add(:base, "Exceeded venue photo limit")
  end
end
```

This is giving me this error:

```
ArgumentError in VenuesController#update

comparison of Fixnum with nil failed
```

**Venue controller**

```
def update
  @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
  if @venue.update_attributes(params[:venue])
    flash[:notice] = 'Venue updated successfully'
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `{:free => 3, :premium => 10}` hash uses Symbols as indices, and the plan would be a String.

```
def photo_limit
  {:free => 3, :premium => 10}[plan.to_sym]
end
```

will work

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much! I'll be back in a few mins to tick it, much appreciated.